# MySQL: How to sync on demand beetwen two database in the same server

Tags: mysql-5.5, data-synchronization

I'll like to know if it's possible to have a systeme on synchronisation beetween two database in the same server.
I have a production database in my server , i want a dev database (same database with another name)
And i want to sync on demand.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

As u told it possible to create another database(with different name) with in the server. try once in local db then you can go into production.

Comment: thank fou your reply , 
But , I want to have one database for production and another for dev. All test will be on test. 
until here , there is no problem.

But i want to sync the dev database with prod database on demand (for example every night , or if there are issues...)

Comment: do u have only one server ?

Comment: yes , @PydiRaju I have only one server

Answer (score 1):

I found an utility that does exactly what I need :
**SQLYog (Database Synchronization Wizard)**